# input type = button access link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following haml code

```
%input{type: "button", value: "Finish"}= link_to "", stop_time_entry_path(time_entry), remote: true
```

How can i access stop_time_entries_path(time_entry) when I click on the button?

It seems very simple but I can't figure it out

Comment: Why is this tagged with `html`? There is no HTML in this question.

Comment: The only difference between haml and html is the syntax.

Comment: What? So instead of having clean markup I got such a soup as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= link_to stop_time_entry_path(time_entry), remote: true do
    %input{type: "button", value: "Finish"}
```

This was the solution .

Answer (score 0):

There is a [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) Rails helper. Try out:

`button_to "Finish", stop_time_entries_path(time_entry), remote: true`

Comment: I need the type to be "button" not "submit" . So it doesn't work :(